# Is it possible to handle convergence in chain of responsibility implementation?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, actor, chain-of-responsibility

I want to implement fan out and convergence in handlers in my implementation. What is best practice to handle such instances. e.g.

```
handler1->handler2,handler3
handler2->handler4
handler3->handler4
handler4->handler5   //this should be executed only if both handlers handler2 and handler3 are completed.
```

Comment: This is highly language/framework/os specific. What are you using?

Comment: My handlers are just classes hosted inside console application, which subscribe to a out proc queue.

Comment: java/c#/js with nodejs?